# How to hide the first item in a column-count without making the first column disappear?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I use script to grab all the images from a post, and place them in a DIV. I style it with `column-count: 3`. Then, I use `:first-of-type { display:none }` to hide the first image. However, doing so actually hides the first column, or causes the first column to collapse, even though there are other images in the first column.

```css
.gallery-masonry { column-count: 3; column-gap: 1rem; }
.gallery-masonry img { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; margin: 0 0 1rem 0; }
.gallery-masonry img:first-of-type { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="gallery-masonry">
     <img src="xxxxx"/>
     <img src="xxxxx"/>
     <img src="xxxxx"/>
     <img src="xxxxx"/>
     <img src="xxxxx"/>
</div>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visibility: hidden;` instead.

```css
.gallery-masonry { column-count: 3; column-gap: 1rem; }
.gallery-masonry img { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; margin: 0 0 1rem 0; }
.gallery-masonry img:first-of-type { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div class="gallery-masonry">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=1"/>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2"/>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=3"/>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=4"/>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=5"/>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=6"/>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=7"/>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=8"/>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=9"/>
</div>
```